# Android App with Local Service go down (Delphi Berlin)

Tags: android, delphi, service, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I made some test application **TestPro** with Local Android Service **TestService2**. In TestPro only one button which starts service.
When I click button, in **Settings -> Apps -> RUNNING** i can see 1 process and 1 service. It's mean Service running OK.
After that i open another applications, best way is open browser and start surf with it (TestPro became inactive). After some time the system will kill TestPro. If i try to activate the programm it will try to start with no success. System ask Wait or Force close the not responding app (**LogCat don't get "Application.Initialize"**). On the second start - the same. On the third time programm starts normally.
Any ideas?

Here is application code:

```
program TestPro;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {FrmMain},
  Androidapi.Helpers,                                   // TAndroidHelper
  AndroidApi.Log,                                       // LOGI
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.ActivityManager in 'Androidapi.JNI.ActivityManager.pas';

var
  LIntent: JIntent;

{$R *.res}

begin
  LogI('Application.Initialize');  // !!!
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TFrmMain, FrmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

In Unit1.pas:

```
unit Unit1;
...
procedure TFrmMain.StartService();
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName(),TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.TestService2'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(LIntent);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartService();
end;
```

Here is Code in Service:

```
function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;
```

PS. Delphi Berlin, SDK 24.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Your service is currently a "started" service so it keeps running even after TestPro has been shut down. It is then still running when the new launch makes an attempt to restart it. Make it a "bound" service in order to avoid that:

Unit1.pas (changed)

```
unit Unit1;
...
procedure TFrmMain.StartService();
var
 LIntent: JIntent;
begin
 LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
 LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName(),TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.TestService2'));
 TAndroidHelper.Activity.BindService(LIntent);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 BindService();
end;
```

This should terminate your service when your application does. 
It can then be restarted on consecutive launches.

The following is from the Android Developer website in regards to services:

> A service can essentially take two forms:
>
> Started 
>   A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity)
>   starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the
>   background indefinitely, **even if the component that started it is destroyed**.
>   Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not return a
>   result to the caller. For example, it might download or upload a file over the
>   network. When the operation is done, the service should stop itself.
>
> Bound 
>   A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by calling 
>   bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server interface that allows 
>   components to interact with the service, send requests, get results, and even 
>   do so across processes with interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service 
>   runs only as long as another application component is bound to it. Multiple 
>   components can bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the 
>   **service is destroyed**.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html